# How to use return a parent and child component separately in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I have a **GetData** component where I make an API call. I then pass the data forward as props to the **graph** components that will use the data. In the app I then return the **GetData** component to render the graphs. The issue is that *both graphs are now merged into one component*. I want to separate them so I can give both components their own box and put a button box next to each.

Is there a way to approach these components separately to give both graphs separate containers and place button components next to them?

This is my code:

GetData:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import GraphChart from "../components/GraphChart";
import BarChart from "../components/BarChart";

const config = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  Accept: "application/json",
};

const GetData = () => {
  const [arrayFlow, setArrayFlow] = useState([]);

  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  useEffect(async () => {
    const { data } = await axios({
      url: "http://192.168.170./*",
      method: "GET",
      data: null,
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: config,
    });
    console.log(data);

    const newData = data.value.map((d) => {
      const idNumber = d._idNumber;
      const startDate =
        d.startDate;
      const endDate =
        d._endDate;
      return {
        idNumber,
        startDate,
        endDate,
      };
    });
    setArrayFlow(newData);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <GraphChart flow={arrayFlow} />
      <BarChart flow={arrayFlow} />
    </>
  );
};
export default GetData;
```

App.js:

```
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import GetData from './apiData/GetData'
import { Button } from "./components/button/Button";
import GraphChart from "./components/GraphChart";

const App = () => {
  
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="example">
        <div className="graph-box">
          <div id="wrapper">
            <GraphChart />
          </div>
          <div className="side-bar">
            <Button>Sort</Button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="graph-box">
          <div id="wrapper">
            <GetData />
          </div>
          <div className="side-bar">
            <Button>Sort</Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Chart, removed clutter:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Chart from "react-apexcharts";
import _ from "lodash";
import { format, parseISO } from "date-fns";

const GraphChart = ({ instroom }) => {
  const [category, setCategory] = useState([]);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let series = [];
    let categories = [];
    let orderedFlow = _.orderBy(
      flow,
      ["startDate"],
      ["asc", "desc"]
    );
    for (let i = 0; i < orderedFlow.length; i++) {
      series.push(orderedFlow[i].idNumber);
      categories = categories.concat(
        format(
          parseISO(orderedFlow[i].startDate),
          "dd MMM YYY"
        )
      );
    }
    setCategory(categories);
    setData(series);
  }, [flow]);

 return (
    <div>
      <Chart
        options={{
          chart: {
            id: "basic-graph",
            }}}
        series={[
          {
            name: "ID",
            data: data,
          },
        ]}
        type="area"
        width="1500"
        height="500"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default GraphChart;
```

Comment: Do you want to divide app js code with `graph-box` class into different component?

Comment: I'd like the build up to stay in the App.js so I can use it to structure the app's layout. I'm new to React so I don't know any best practices yet, so if there's a better way to achieve the same goal I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create a `useGetData` hook, instead of using the `<GetData/>` component?

That hook will be responsible for fetching the data. You can call it from the parent of both of your `<Graphs/>` and provide the data to both of them.

The `useGetData` code would look something like this:

**useGetData.js**

```
const useGetData = () => { // You can also pass some params to it
  const [data,setData] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading,setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error,setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // CALL AXIOS
    
    // ON SUCCESS
    // setData(data) and setIsLoading(false)

    // ON ERROR
    // setError(error) and setIsLoading(false)
  },[]);

  return {
    data,
    isLoading,
    error
  };

};
```

**App.js**

```
const { data, isLoading, error } = useGetdata();

return (
  isLoading ? <Spinner/>
  : error ? <Error/>
  : <Chart1 data={data}/> and <Chart2 data={data}/>
);
```

Comment: I've tried to set it up like this (and renamed some variables) but the only problem I'm facing right now is that when I pas `data` to my `GraphChart` from the app, it seems like the data isn't passed on. I'm able to log it in the `App.js` and the `userGetData.js` but not in the `GraphChart.js`.

From the `app.js`: `<GraphChart graphData=dataNew}/>`
The `GraphChart` first line: `const GraphChart = ({ graphData }) => {`

Comment: Double check your implementation. If you are logging from the parent, and passing it the correct way to the child, it must be there! Unless your child component is doing something weird (like memoizing and not being updated for some reason), but this is not normal. Replace it with a very basic component and see if you can log the props.

Comment: I tried it on the BarChart and it worked flawlessly! I'll see if I can fix the other chart as well, thanks a lot!

Comment: There are libraries that do specifically those tasks of querying data from the backend. If you are building something more complex, you probably gonna need one of those. `react-query`, `relay`,  `swr`, `apollo-client`, etc.